# Use two queries or allow PHP to sort: Which is generally faster?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a single table that contains two types of items under the same class/category. I want to use php to output two lists, each containing each type of item. Would it be generally faster and more acceptable to sort them by using two queries or just query them all and then just PHP to sort them using `if($type == 'blah')` statements?

Which is generally more recommended/acceptable?

I am aware of benchmarking but I would like a general opinion/standard, as benchmarking can usually be very dependant on other factors.

**Sample result set**

```
entry_id   user_id  element_id  saved_date  saved_type
    65     1         20         1315473732  listing
    66     1         22         1315473735  listing
    49     1         5          1315429549  user
    62     1         1          1315470500  user
    70     1         15         1315473763  listing
    72     1         2          1315476924  listing
```

In general, results shouldn't exceed more than 100 records in total. Example output is basically this result set separated into two tables "Saved Listings" and "Saved Users".

Comment: Answer on this question is surely too very dependent on other factors you didn't mention.

Comment: I'd say this depends heavily on resultset size..

Comment: the *general opinion/standard* is useless when the *concrete other factors* result in the *general opinion/standard* not applying to your scenario. In other words: use a profiler and see what works better.

Comment: Benchmark yourself, on your data

Comment: And it depends heavily on what you are going to do with those items. It's almost for sure that some day you'll want to process one type of items in some special way, or add another type of items, or whatsoever.

Comment: Could you provide a sample result set with column headings?

Comment: Please add an example input and desired output.

Comment: I don't think the silent trigger happy downvoters understand what this question is about. I was asking whether there was any significant deep-level technical difference in between using SQL or PHP, not whether the specific query or situation outlined in the question would be faster or not.

Also it's common courtesy to mention specifically why such a question warrants your downvote.

Comment: So, you were asking which is faster - mysql or PHP in general? Well, you are to expect more downvotes then

Comment: +1 because you bring up a good argument. The example is not great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ease of understanding**
I think it's a bad pattern if you write complicated code in php, that can be trivally coded in SQL, see @Col Shrapnel's answer.

The top SQL statement

```
$type1 = $db->getArr("SELECT * FROM table WHERE type=1");
```

is instantly clear: get all items with type = 1.

The bottom one requires scanning. Also note that @Col shrapnel's top and bottom code samples are not 100% equivalent! This is a minor oversight I'm sure, but sometimes it can be really hard to write equivalent code to SQL in php, SQL differs in subtle ways from procedural logic that can be very hard to grok.
**SQL wins**

**Network load**
Running tiome is one time thing, but you also need to take network load into account.
If you do a `select *` and then soft out the results in php, that means data (may) need to cross the network, a very slow medium.
This is a waste of resources and the network time can easily outweigh all other time factors.
**SQL wins**

**Pure running time**
This is a hard one too call, SQL has indexes on the data that it can (re)use to sort the data, however sometimes it does too much work and php will be a faster choose.
I would contest though that because SQL has more information available (in the form of indexes) to handle the data fast.
There are also (many) tricks you can use e.g. `SQL_SMALL_RESULT` to force MySQL to keep the data in memory and not use disk for temp-storage.
**To close too call**

**Architecturally**
If you design an application, and the underlying database changes, which option would make be easier to redesign, which is more robust.
If you do all the work in SQL and always present standardized results to php, you can seperate the php code from the database.
If you do half your database processing in php, you lose that advantage.
This kind of tight coupling between the raw database and php is a clear fail in my opinion and a well known anti-pattern.
**SQL wins**

**Closing argument**
I can go on, but I would like to rest my case and declare SQL the clear winner.
php can maybe score a few points on a minor issue, but I doubt the few cases where it is faster are sufficiently important to overcome the disadvantages you are heaping on your project.
I think you are also underestimating the many ways in which SQL can be optimized.

Answer (score 1):

If I took your question correctly, then sort them out in PHP.

However, I wouldn't say there is a big difference.
For sake of the neater code i'd write

```
$type1 = $db->getArr("SELECT * FROM table WHERE type=1");
$type2 = $db->getArr("SELECT * FROM table WHERE type=2");
```

rather than

```
$type1 = array();
$type2 = array();
$res = $db->start("SELECT * FROM table");
while($row = $db->next($res)) {
  if ($row['type'] = 1){
    $type1[] = $row;
  } else {
    $type2[] = $row;
  }
}
```

That's not the question one have to ponder heavily of.